# Bootstrap Carousel images are not responsive

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

It seems that the bootstrap carousel images are being given a height/width attribute by views or bootstrap_views. This means that when the page is resized, or indeed viewed on a smaller screen/device the image is cut off as the carousel "window" is shrunk. The image in shrink in mobile devices. Also caption is not aligned properly in mobile devices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try by adding img-responsive class.

Comment: i have used the same carousel in bootstrap 4. It is not responsive in mobile